# how to create side panel custom search for leaflet that search through geojson data?

Tags: leaflet

I have a project using leaflet, but I want to do a custom search through GeoJSON data but I don't know how to do it. I have a side panel with search box and button. below is my design:[image].

```
<div
  id="leaflet_search"
  class="leaflet-control-search leaflet-control search-exp"
>
  <input
    class="search-input"
    type="text"
    autocapitalize="off"
    placeholder="Search..."
    id="searchtext10"
    style="display: block; max-width: 634px;"
  />
  <ul class="search-tooltip" style="display: none;"></ul>
  <a class="search-cancel" href="#" title="Cancel" style="display: none;">
    <span>⊗</span>
  </a>
  <a class="search-button" id="search" href="#" title="Search..." style=""></a>
  <div class="search-alert" style="display: none;"></div>
</div>
```

---

```
var map = new L.map("myMAP_id", {
  fullscreenControl: {
    pseudoFullscreen: false,
    position: "topright"
  }
}).setView([10.392241, 124.98], 16.5);
var layer = new L.tileLayer(
  "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
  {
    attribution:
      '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
    visible: false,
    title: "OpenStreetMap"
  }
);

map.addLayer(layer);

var poly = L.geoJson(slsu_bldg, {
  style: function(feature) {
    return bldg_style;
  },
  onEachFeature: function(feature, marker) {
    marker.bindPopup(
      "<div><b>SOUTHERN LEYTE STATE UNIVERSITY" +
        "<br>" +
        feature.properties.BLDG_NAME +
        "<br><button id='" +
        feature.properties.ID +
        "' class='btn btn-xs btn-primary' style='height: 23px; font-size: 11px; padding: 3px 6px; letter-spacing: 0.02rem; margin-top: 5px;'>More Details <i class='fa fa-caret-right'></i></button></div"
    );
  }
});

var search_val;
$("#search").on("click", function() {
  search_val = $("#searchtext10").val();

  console.log(search_val);
  var search = new L.Control.Search({
    options: {
      layer: poly,
      zoom: 19,
      initial: false,
      filterData: search_val,
      propertyName: "BLDG_NAME",
      marker: {
        icon: true,
        animate: true,
        circle: {
          radius: 10,
          weight: 4,
          color: "#1BC500",
          stroke: true,
          fill: true
        }
      }
    }
  });

  console.log(search);
});
```

---

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>SLSU Asset Management</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://localhost/GIS-SLSU_AssetMgt/assets/img/slsu.png" />

    <!-- offline bootstrap -->

    <!-- online bootstrap -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <!-- custom stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/GIS-SLSU_AssetMgt/assets/custom/style.css" />
    <!-- leaflet offline connection -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="http://localhost/GIS-SLSU_AssetMgt/assets/leaflet/leaflet.css"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="http://localhost/GIS-SLSU_AssetMgt/assets/leaflet/leaflet.label/leaflet.label.css"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="http://localhost/GIS-SLSU_AssetMgt/assets/leaflet/leaflet-search.css"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="http://localhost/GIS-SLSU_AssetMgt/assets/leaflet/leaflet-sidebar.css"
    />
    <script src="http://localhost/GIS-SLSU_AssetMgt/assets/leaflet/leaflet.label/leaflet.label.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/GIS-SLSU_AssetMgt/assets/leaflet/leaflet-src.js">
      integrity="sha512-eldJj3obVsCO9Tlrj/J8AFrrTFD4+sN8d9HdwKAqZuSgHloWOm6IzetLy1uQnwh9qLssrY3TAgIJQfjPfQJxHQ=="
      crossorigin=""
    </script>
    <script src="http://localhost/GIS-SLSU_AssetMgt/assets/leaflet/leaflet-sidebar.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/GIS-SLSU_AssetMgt/assets/leaflet/leaflet-search.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/GIS-SLSU_AssetMgt/assets/leaflet/L.Conttol.Locate.min.js"></script>

    <!-- leaflet full screen -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="http://localhost/GIS-SLSU_AssetMgt/assets/leaflet/leaflet.fullscreen.css"
    />
    <script src="http://localhost/GIS-SLSU_AssetMgt/assets/leaflet/leaflet.fullscreen.min.js"></script>

    <!-- online maptiler mapboxGL map -->
    <script src="https://cdn.maptiler.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.53.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.maptiler.com/mapbox-gl-leaflet/latest/leaflet-mapbox-gl.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.maptiler.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.53.0/mapbox-gl.css" />

    <!-- offline maptiler mapboxGL map -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="http://localhost/GIS-SLSU_AssetMgt/assets/mapbox-gl/mapbox-gl.css"
    />
    <script src="http://localhost/GIS-SLSU_AssetMgt/assets/mapbox-gl/leaflet-mapbox-gl.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/GIS-SLSU_AssetMgt/assets/mapbox-gl/mapbox-gl.js"></script>

    <!-- geojson coder -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-control-geocoder/dist/Control.Geocoder.css"
    />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/osmtogeojson@2.2.12/osmtogeojson.js"></script>

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="http://localhost/GIS-SLSU_AssetMgt/assets/osm/OSMBuildings.css"
    />
    <script src="http://localhost/GIS-SLSU_AssetMgt/assets/osm/OSMBuildings.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--- navigation bar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand image" href="#">
        <img
          class="img img-responsive"
          src="http://localhost/GIS-SLSU_AssetMgt/assets/img/LOGO.png"
          alt=""
        />
        <!-- SLSU-MC GIS MAP -->
      </a>
      <button
        class="navbar-toggler"
        type="button"
        data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#navbarColor01"
        aria-controls="navbarColor01"
        aria-expanded="false"
        aria-label="Toggle navigation"
      >
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor01">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="http://localhost/GIS-SLSU_AssetMgt"
              >Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a
            >
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="http://localhost/GIS-SLSU_AssetMgt/map">Map</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="http://localhost/GIS-SLSU_AssetMgt/about">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="http://localhost/GIS-SLSU_AssetMgt/#">Features</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="http://localhost/GIS-SLSU_AssetMgt/#">Help</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!---map section -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 map_wrapper">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-right: 0 !important;">
              <div class="left-control">
                <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
                      <h2 class="mb-0">
                        <a class="leaflet-control-layers-toggle toggle" href="#"></a>
                        <button
                          class="btn btn-link"
                          type="button"
                          data-toggle="collapse"
                          data-target="#collapseOne"
                          aria-expanded="true"
                          aria-controls="collapseOne"
                        >
                          BASE MAPS
                        </button>
                      </h2>
                    </div>
                    <div
                      id="collapseOne"
                      class="collapse show"
                      aria-labelledby="headingOne"
                      data-parent="#accordionExample"
                    >
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <div
                          class="leaflet-control-layers leaflet-control leaflet-control-layers-expanded"
                          aria-haspopup="true"
                        >
                          <section class="leaflet-control-layers-list">
                            <div class="leaflet-control-layers-base">
                              <label>
                                <div>
                                  <input
                                    type="radio"
                                    id="basemaps"
                                    value="OpenStreetMap"
                                    class="leaflet-control-layers-selector"
                                    name="leaflet-base-layers_264"
                                    checked="checked"
                                  />
                                  <span> Open Street Map</span>
                                </div>
                              </label>
                              <label>
                                <div>
                                  <input
                                    type="radio"
                                    id="basemaps"
                                    value="Maptiler"
                                    class="leaflet-control-layers-selector"
                                    name="leaflet-base-layers_264"
                                  />
                                  <span> Maptiler</span>
                                </div>
                              </label>
                              <label>
                                <div>
                                  <input
                                    type="radio"
                                    id="basemaps"
                                    value="MapBox"
                                    class="leaflet-control-layers-selector"
                                    name="leaflet-base-layers_264"
                                  />
                                  <span> MapBox</span>
                                </div>
                              </label>
                              <label>
                                <div>
                                  <input
                                    type="radio"
                                    id="basemaps"
                                    value="Google"
                                    class="leaflet-control-layers-selector"
                                    name="leaflet-base-layers_264"
                                  />
                                  <span> Google</span>
                                </div>
                              </label>
                              <label>
                                <div>
                                  <input
                                    type="radio"
                                    id="basemaps"
                                    value="WorldImagery"
                                    class="leaflet-control-layers-selector"
                                    name="leaflet-base-layers_264"
                                  />
                                  <span> World Imagery</span>
                                </div>
                              </label>
                            </div>
                          </section>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
                      <h2 class="mb-0">
                        <a class="leaflet-control-layers-toggle toggle" href="#"></a>
                        <button
                          class="btn btn-link collapsed"
                          type="button"
                          data-toggle="collapse"
                          data-target="#collapseTwo"
                          aria-expanded="false"
                          aria-controls="collapseTwo"
                        >
                          LAYER MAPS
                        </button>
                      </h2>
                    </div>
                    <div
                      id="collapseTwo"
                      class="collapse"
                      aria-labelledby="headingTwo"
                      data-parent="#accordionExample"
                    >
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <div
                          class="leaflet-control-layers leaflet-control leaflet-control-layers-expanded"
                          aria-haspopup="true"
                        >
                          <section class="leaflet-control-layers-list">
                            <div class="leaflet-control-layers-overlays">
                              <label>
                                <div>
                                  <input
                                    type="checkbox"
                                    id="vector_layerBuilding"
                                    value="Buildings"
                                    class="leaflet-control-layers-selector"
                                    checked=""
                                    onclick="vector_layerBuilding()"
                                  />
                                  <span> Buildings</span>
                                </div>
                              </label>
                              <label>
                                <div>
                                  <input
                                    type="checkbox"
                                    id="vector_layerRoads"
                                    value="Roads"
                                    class="leaflet-control-layers-selector"
                                    onclick="vector_roads()"
                                  />
                                  <span> Roads</span>
                                </div>
                              </label>
                              <label>
                                <div>
                                  <input
                                    type="checkbox"
                                    id="vector_layerBoundary"
                                    value="Boundary"
                                    class="leaflet-control-layers-selector"
                                    onclick="vector_layerBoundary()"
                                  />
                                  <span> Boundary</span>
                                </div>
                              </label>
                              <label>
                                <div>
                                  <input
                                    type="checkbox"
                                    id="vector_layerTrack"
                                    value="Track/Oval"
                                    class="leaflet-control-layers-selector"
                                    onclick="vector_layerTrack()"
                                  />
                                  <span> Track/Oval</span>
                                </div>
                              </label>
                              <label>
                                <div>
                                  <input
                                    type="checkbox"
                                    id="vector_layerField"
                                    value="Field"
                                    class="leaflet-control-layers-selector"
                                    onclick="vector_layerField()"
                                  />
                                  <span> Field</span>
                                </div>
                              </label>
                              <label>
                                <div>
                                  <input
                                    type="checkbox"
                                    id="vector_layerParking"
                                    value="Parking Lot"
                                    class="leaflet-control-layers-selector"
                                    onclick="vector_layerParking()"
                                  />
                                  <span> Parking Lot</span>
                                </div>
                              </label>
                              <label>
                                <div>
                                  <input
                                    type="checkbox"
                                    id="vector_layerPath"
                                    value="Foot Path"
                                    class="leaflet-control-layers-selector"
                                    onclick="vector_layerPath()"
                                  />
                                  <span> Foot Path</span>
                                </div>
                              </label>
                              <label>
                                <div>
                                  <input
                                    type="checkbox"
                                    id="vector_layerBleacher"
                                    value="Bleacher"
                                    class="leaflet-control-layers-selector"
                                    onclick="vector_layerBleacher()"
                                  />
                                  <span> Bleacher</span>
                                </div>
                              </label>
                            </div>
                          </section>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div
                  id="leaflet_search"
                  class="leaflet-control-search leaflet-control search-exp"
                >
                  <input
                    class="search-input"
                    type="text"
                    autocapitalize="off"
                    placeholder="Search..."
                    id="searchtext10"
                    style="display: block; max-width: 634px;"
                  />
                  <ul class="search-tooltip" style="display: none;"></ul>
                  <a class="search-cancel" href="#" title="Cancel" style="display: none;">
                    <span>⊗</span>
                  </a>
                  <a class="search-button" id="search" href="#" title="Search..." style=""></a>
                  <div class="search-alert" style="display: none;"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div id="myMAP_id"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="info" style="height: 28vh">
                    <div align="right"><button class="btn btn-default">IMPORT</button></div>
                    <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Id</th>
                          <th>Building Name</th>
                          <th>Assets</th>
                          <th>Counts</th>
                          <th>Unit</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td>1</td>
                          <td>CCSIT Building</td>
                          <td>Computer Sets</td>
                          <td>100</td>
                          <td>PCS</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>2</td>
                          <td>CCSIT Building</td>
                          <td>MAC PC</td>
                          <td>25</td>
                          <td>PCS</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>3</td>
                          <td>CCSIT Building</td>
                          <td>Mga Gwapo</td>
                          <td>Gamay Ra Me!</td>
                          <td>Way Labot Jorton (by: Ranel)</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>4</td>
                          <td>CCSIT Building</td>
                          <td>Mga Panget</td>
                          <td>Gamay Ra Sila!</td>
                          <td>Labot Si Jorton (by: Ranel)</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <p>
            <a href="https://leafletjs.com/" target="_blank">Leaflet ©</a
            ><a href="#" target="_blank"> | Developed by: darksidebug_09 </a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--- scripts here -->
    <!--- geojson data -->
    <script src="http://localhost/GIS-SLSU_AssetMgt/assets/geoJson/new_bldg_data.geojson"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/GIS-SLSU_AssetMgt/assets/geoJson/slsu_boundary.geojson"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/GIS-SLSU_AssetMgt/assets/geoJson/road_network.geojson"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/GIS-SLSU_AssetMgt/assets/geoJson/track_oval.geojson"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/GIS-SLSU_AssetMgt/assets/geoJson/slsu_field.geojson"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/GIS-SLSU_AssetMgt/assets/geoJson/parking_lot.geojson"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/GIS-SLSU_AssetMgt/assets/geoJson/foot_path.geojson"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/GIS-SLSU_AssetMgt/assets/geoJson/bleacher.geojson"></script>

    <!--- script -->
    <script src="http://localhost/GIS-SLSU_AssetMgt/assets/leaflet/data_scripts.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript and JQuery-->
    <script src="http://localhost/GIS-SLSU_AssetMgt/assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/GIS-SLSU_AssetMgt/assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you want to do when you found the right data? And pls share your code from geojson data and you map + geoJSON Layer

Comment: what i'm trying to do is to locate and display it to the map on button click...but it didn't do anything.

Comment: thanks everyone. But I found a way to change where the search control to be displayed. It is displayed where I want it to be.